# One return for conditional case REACT

Tags: reactjs, return, conditional-statements

I have below in My App function

```
 if (score.total === 0)
  {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header content="give feedback"/>
        <ChoiceButton choice="good" handleClick={handleClickGood}/>
        <ChoiceButton choice="neutral" handleClick={handleClickNeutral}/>
        <ChoiceButton choice="bad" handleClick={handleClickBad}/>
        <Header content="statistics"/>
        <div>No feedback given.</div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header content="give feedback"/>
      <ChoiceButton choice="good" handleClick={handleClickGood}/>
      <ChoiceButton choice="neutral" handleClick={handleClickNeutral}/>
      <ChoiceButton choice="bad" handleClick={handleClickBad}/>
      <Header content="statistics"/>
      <Statistics score={score} good={good} neutral={neutral} bad={bad}/>
      <StatisticsAll count={score.count}/>  
    </div>
  )
```

The first 5 lines in the div in return are duplicate. I want to have only one return and not write the first 5 lines again. Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: A simple loop will solve this issue, please reconsider reading the docs before posting a question or try to research more on the question if you are stuck to see if answer to your solution already exist. Thanks :)

Comment: @Gopherine I started to learn react few days back and my approach has been doing small codes as i proceed instead of reading the doc completely in one go, I did search for different keywords but was unable to find the correct keywords for this issue. Only after Hongji answered i got reference to usage of <></> and eventually ref to Fragments in reactjs docs.. 
I apologize for the trouble. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give condition inside return()

```
  return (
    <div>
      <Header content="give feedback" />
      <ChoiceButton choice="good" handleClick={handleClickGood} />
      <ChoiceButton choice="neutral" handleClick={handleClickNeutral} />
      <ChoiceButton choice="bad" handleClick={handleClickBad} />
      <Header content="statistics" />
      {score.total === 0 ? (
        <div>No feedback given.</div>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Statistics score={score} good={good} neutral={neutral} bad={bad} />
          <StatisticsAll count={score.count} />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```